# AWS S3 ACL Policy Condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I'm trying to set up my role policy for S3. What I'm trying to do is allow users to get out any images that contain "public" in their name. The problem is that I've seem to of gotten the correct policy (it succeeds in the policy simulator) but when I'm running it in my app it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Here is my policy:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "*public*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`

I am setting the `s3:prefix` as `user1/image1-public`. Like I mentioned before, on the policy simulator, it allows all "Get" and "List" commands (just like it should).

The problem is when I'm downloading an example image from the database using the transfer manager in the iOS app, I get the following error:

`2015-10-07 14:22:01.716 SimpleAuth[71584:8584520] Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 1.)" UserInfo=0x7fcbf2d8c560 {HostId=ke/f5x+DKCnjuzlbH5XBWCQfawbkUIRWWhPcY9LdqjPqP5kUyq0rzIjkqeL+8Bm/fvr/l24Wm94=, Message=Access Denied, Code=AccessDenied, RequestId=180803E4DDD0BB73}`

The code that I have in the Xcode project is

```
AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *downloadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];

downloadRequest.bucket = @"test";
downloadRequest.key = @"user1/image1-public";
downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL;

// Download the file.
[[transferManager download:downloadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                       withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task)
{
    if (task.error){
        if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
           switch (task.error.code) {
               case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
               case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                   break;

               default:
                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                   break;
           }
        } else {
           // Unknown error.
           NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        }
    }

    if (task.result)
    {
        AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput *downloadOutput = task.result;
        //File downloaded successfully.

        NSLog(@"Now go to the next screen");

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccessSegue" sender:self];

    }
    return nil;
    }];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've never been able to get a "Condition" to work on an ACL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"s3:prefix": "*public*"` will essentially never match anything meaningful.

It specifies a **prefix** -- not a wildcard match.

To match the image object at `/user-1/image/public/kitten.jpg` and everything else at the same level of structure, the policy condition would need to be `"s3:prefix": "user-1/image/public/"`

For a policy like this to work, the "public" needs to be at the far left of the path -- the prefix.

The documentation is unclear, but it is *possible* that instead of a condition, you could use a wildcard in the resource.  It says, simply, ["You can use wild card."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html).  If true, then perhaps something along these lines:

```
"Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*/public/*"
            ],
```

If not, you're limited to prefixes again, which would be what I suspect may be the case.

I would have thought, though, that there would have been a warning from the policy simulator, something like this, to let you know that the policy simulator does not thoroughly evaluate all aspects of the policy, for some services:

> **“**This action belongs to a service that supports access control mechanisms attached to resources. The simulator does not model these mechanisms, so results may differ in your production environment.**”**
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html

Comment: Ahhh ok! Thank you! Btw, using a wildcard in the Resource name works and will be how I implement what I want to do. Thanks again =)